# Hacer aplicacion que se ejecute hasta una hora determinada en python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de hacer un web spyder que obtenga información de la web. El problema es que normalmente cuando el programa cumple sus objetivos ya deja de funcionar, sin embargo las paginas de las que obtengo información se estan actualizando continuamente por lo que quiero que mi programa se ejecute continuamente sin parar de un horario a otro. Por ejemplo de 3 de la mañana a 6 de la tarde.

No se tecnicamente como se puede hacer en programacion esto para que la aplicacion se ejecute continuamente por lo que agradeceria cualquier tipo de ayuda.

un saludo y gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

No se que sistema operativo estés trabajando en linux y derivados puedes poner una entrada en el crontab. Ejemplo:

```
15 10 * * * usuario /home/usuario/scripts/actualizar.sh
```

El script actualizar.sh se ejecutara todos los días a las 10 con 15 min.

En windows en una tarea programada.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la solución viene con datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time
hora_inicio = time(3,0,0) # tres de la mañana
hora_finalizacion = time(6,0,0) # seis de la mañana
while True:
    actual = datetime.now()
    actual = time(actual.hour, actual.minute,actual.second)  # este objeto se puede comparar sin tener en cuenta la fecha
    if actual > hora_inicio and actual < hora_finalizacion:
        web_spider()
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

No conozco a detalle tu implementación, pero podría ser algo así

```
import time

while true:
    web_spider()
    time.sleep(intervalo_de_tiempo_en_segundos)
```

Puedes revisar con más detalle como trabajar con el metodo `time` [aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm)

Comment: Pero el método sleep pone a dormir el programa durante el tiempo que le pongas. Yo quiero que el programa no se duerma sino que se ejecute indefinidamente desde una hora a otra hora, no quiero que pare

Comment: Ok, entiendo
¿No te serviría entonces sencillamente eliminar el `time.sleep`?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto es lo más simple que haría.

```
from datetime import time

start_time = time(3, 0, 0)
end_time = time(6, 0, 0)
while datetime.time.now() > start_time and datetime.time.now() < end_time:
    llama_funcion()
```

Espero haber ayudado.